# Change text/icon color in top bar

Tags: maui, .net-maui

How do I change the color of the text and icon's in the very top bar.  I want to change the backgroundcolor of that bar to a light color, which I know how to do, I can't figure out how to make the text/icon's darker.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StatusBarBehavior` from MAUI toolkit package, as a `Behavior` at a `ContentPage` level:

```xml
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="LightGreen" StatusBarStyle="DarkContent" />
</ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

or by calling the provided methods:

```c#
CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform.StatusBar.SetColor(Colors.LightGreen);
CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Platform.StatusBar.SetStyle(StatusBarStyle.DarkContent);
```

[StatusBarBehavior docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/statusbar-behavior?tabs=ios)