# Statusbar theme only changes after restarting app

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

My apps statusbar does not seem to react to android system theme changes while the app is loaded.

The statusbar only updates after a restart.  Please see videos below:

This video shows the light theme correctly applied to the app's statusbar when loaded.  But after loading the app, if the user changes the system theme to dark, the statusbar of the app does not update until the app is restarted.

[Light to dark theme example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1abX8vxTjH7CDMNNAT_ebl8rRX5NAWMoH/view?usp=share_link).

This video shows the dark theme correctly applied to the app's statusbar when loaded.  But after loading the app, if the users changes the system theme to light, the statusbar of the app does not update until the app is restarted.

[Dark to light theme example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wcUYb7Nsz8qe0z4yn34Rlj73r03wuiLD/view?usp=share_link).

Anyone know how to get the statusbar to react to system theme changes while having the app loaded?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

The following returns the value of the selected theme in the console, but as soon as I uncomment `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;` no values are returned in the console when I change the system theme.

```
private void ChangeTheme()
{
    Application.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, a) =>
    {
        AppTheme currentTheme = Application.Current.RequestedTheme;

        if (currentTheme is AppTheme.Dark)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentTheme.ToString());
            //Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;
        }
        else if (currentTheme is AppTheme.Light)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentTheme.ToString());
        }
    };
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I am using 2 different styles.xml files in Platforms > Android > Resources > values and values-night to set the statusbarcolor.

Comment: Are you using the Community Toolkit's `StatusBarBehavior` or are you setting the status bar color by calling `Window.SetStatusBarColor()` from the MainActivity? In case of the latter, you could subscribe to the `RequestedThemeChanged` event in your `App` class and set the status bar color based on the current selection.

Comment: I am using 2 different styles.xml files in Platforms > Android > Resources > values and values-night to set the statusbarcolor.

Comment: And you are not overriding this anywhere? Didn't you use `StatusBarBehvavior` previously (in a different SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74103489/change-text-icon-color-in-top-bar/74103552#74103552)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainActivity.cs` you can override the `OnConfigurationChanged()` method and listen to UI configuration changes:

```cs
public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.R)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (newConfig.IsNightModeActive)
    {
        Window?.SetStatusBarColor(Colors.Black.ToAndroid());
        Window?.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance(0, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars);
    }
    else
    {
        Window?.SetStatusBarColor(Colors.White.ToAndroid());
        Window?.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance((int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars);
    }
}
```

You also need to include the `ConfigChanges.UiMode` flag in the `ConfigurationChanges` attribute (included by default in new MAUI projects):

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyAppTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
```

**UPDATE**

About the `RequestedThemeChanged` event and the `RequestedTheme` property in your case: When you are setting `Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;` you are effectively saying that you want the theme to be set to **Dark** permanently, so the event doesn't get raised anymore after that, since `UserAppTheme` is not set to `Unspecified` anymore. See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes#set-the-current-user-theme

Comment: That works.  I think I now only have 1 remaining theme style issue.  I'll create a new ticket for that.  Thanks again!